# How come the last character is taken in twice before the file resets?

Tags: c++, file-io, char, eof

I have a function that takes input from a file, character by character:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

ifstream input("sequence.txt");

char getChar(){
 char nextType;
 if (input.eof()) {
  input.clear();
  input.seekg(0,ios::beg);
 }      
 input >> nextType;
 return nextType;
}

int main(){
 for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    cout << getChar() << endl;
}
return 0;
}
```

The input inside "sequence.txt" is:

```
I O
```

So the output should print alternating I's and O's, but instead outputs:

```
I O O I O O I O O I
```

How do I make the file reset after the first time it reads the last character in the file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`eof` is only set when you try to read after already reaching the end of the file.  Instead, first try to read a char.  If that fails, then reset the stream and try again, like this:

```
char getChar()
{
    char nextType;
    if (!(input >> nextType))
    {
        input.clear();
        input.seekg(0,ios::beg);
        input >> nextType;
    }
    return nextType;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I never considered this method. I appreciate the help.

Comment: Even that's not correct.  You fail to verify that the second read succeeded.  Consider what might happen if the file was empty, or contained just spaces.

Comment: @JamesKanze: I was operating under preconditions set forth in the question.  The extra information is fine, but I think the answer to the actual question is simply the explanation of how eof works, and how to get around the behavior.

Answer (score 0):

You're returning a value without testing whether the input
succeeded.  You're function should be something alont the lines
of:

```
char
getChar()
{
    char results;
    input >> results;
    if ( !input ) {
        input.clear();
        input.seekg( 0, std::ios_base:;beg );
        input >> results;
        if ( !input ) {
            //  There are no non-blanks in the input, so there's no way we're
            //  going to read one.  Give up, generating some error condition
            //  (Throw an exception?)
        }
    }
    return results;
}
```

The important thing is that there is *no* path of execution
which reads or copies `results` without having successfully read
it.  (Unless you've assigned something to it otherwise.  You
might, for example, initialize it with `'\0'`, with the
convention that the function returns `'\0'` if it is unable to
read anything.)

I might add that the test for `input.eof()` is only valid
*after* you've determined that an input has failed.  I may
return false even when there's no more valid input.